# Type of questions in Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

Can we get answers for general knowledge questions in Meta Stack Exchange or only tech related ones?

Comment: There's a [help] where you can read what and how to ask here.

Comment: You're not new here, so I'm curious, what led you to think "general knowledge questions" or "tech related  questions" are on topic here to begin with? If we'll know the source of your confusion, maybe we can prevent others from getting confused.

Answer (score 7):

Neither of those. You can basically only ask questions *about* Stack Exchange here. If you don't know where your question should go, you can post a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) question.

See also the Help Center article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).